# What is the subject in this quoted sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence, subjects, grammatical-roles

> "But perhaps most importantly, UF simply should not be looking to Governor DeSantis to **decide** which speech activities it will permit its employees and students to engage in,” the ACLU’s Daniel Tilley wrote to university officials.

Is the subject, as regards the verb "decide", here "UF" or "Governor DeSantis"?

Comment: **ᴍᴏᴅᴇʀᴀᴛᴏʀ ɴᴏᴛᴇ:** Please do not answer in comments. Write an answer. It can even be an 
incomplete germ of an answer, but please put it in the right place. The
Q&A system cannot cope with answers in comments, and will not mark the question as
answered if you do that. Answering in comments circumvents the very
facilities that allow our Q&A community to police itself and maintain site
quality. If the question requires closing, then please vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

The quoted sentence is

> But perhaps most importantly, UF simply should not be looking to Governor DeSantis to decide which speech activities it will permit its employees and students to engage in.

The subject of the overall sentence is UF.
"Governor DeSantis to decide..." is an infinitive clause whose subject is "Governor DeSantis".

The  phrase  "should not be looking to GDS to decide" is equivalent to "should not be expecting GDS to decide".

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence, with bells and whistles removed, asking about the subject of *decide*:

> *UF should not look to Governor DeSantis to **decide** which ...*

The answer is ambiguous. The original writer may have intended to refer to the governor doing the deciding, as he is clearly trying to do, or they may have intended to refer to the UF (University of Florida) being the decider, as it normally would. The *look to* construction doesn't forbid either one.

One of the problems with long complicated sentences of the kind one finds in official brouhahas like this is that they tend not to be clear. This is a good example.